# How to type functions overloaded using a union type

Tags: typescript

I am not sure if I formulated the question correctly, but how to type the `getFoo`'s return:

```js
type T = number | string

function f(fooType: string, arg?: T): string {
    const defaultArg = 0;
    const foo1 = (arg: string): string => {
        return '' + arg;
    }

    const foo2 = (arg: number): string => {
        return '' + arg;
    }

    const getFoo = (fooType: string): ??? => {
        switch (fooType) {
            case 'bar':
                return foo1
            default:
                return foo2
        }
    }

    const foo = getFoo(fooType)
    return foo(arg || defaultArg)
}
```

Here is a link to CodeSandbox showing lint error: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snowflake-6jiiu?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 3):

In order to call a function that is a union of functions, typescript will only allow the intersection of those functions. Which makes sense, because if you don't know which member of the union it is, you must call it in a way that satisfies all functions.

Let's say you have:

```
type A = (a: number) => void | (a: string) => void
```

The safe way to call a function of this type is with an argument of `number & string`. Since a type cannot be both a number and a string, typescript decides the argument can only be of type `never`, prevent you from passing the required argument.

This is exactly what you are doing when you do `GetFoo1 | GetFoo2`.

Whatever you're trying for here won't work. The code is not type safe because:

1. Call `f('bar')` with no `arg`.
2. `const foo = getFoo(fooType)` returns a function that takes a string argument.
3. `foo(arg || default)` will send a number to a function that requires a string.

I'm not sure how to tell you "fix" this because the example is so contrived. But your approach here isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I've updated the question. How to type the getFoo function?

Comment: You can't do it. Not in a type safe way. You need to change you approach here. Again, it's hard to help more without knowing what your goal is from this contrived example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you cannot type-check the argument given to `foo` because you don't know which `foo` is selected. You will need to cast the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your code problem is here:

```
const foo = getFoo(fooType)
```

The return type of `foo` is a function which is `((arg: string) => string) | ((arg: number) => string)`, so typescript don't know, which one it is, so it infer the result as the type `never`. Then your next line code gets a problem.

To solve this problem, just simply coerce the output of the `foo` to `any`, then everything will be fine:

```
const foo:any = getFoo(fooType)
```

However, I think, the typescript's "function overloading" feature can solve your problem better:

```
function foo(fooType: string, arg?: string):string
function foo(fooType: string, arg?: number):string
function foo(fooType: string, arg?: any):any{
  const defaultArg = ""
  switch (fooType) {
    case 'foo1':
      return arg || defaultArg
    default:
      return arg?.toString()||defaultArg
  }
}
```

please see here: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading